# Should I use `registerOnChange` or `valueChanges` on a form control

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

It seems that I can listen to changes on the control using `registerOnChange` or `valueChanges` method. I'm confused as to when to use what. `valueChanges` returns observable, so it makes sense to work with it as it provides many handy methods. When to use `registerOnChange` then?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `registerOnChange` is available just for `FormControl`. There is a [link to source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts#L754):

```
export class FormControl extends AbstractControl {
    ...
    /**
    * Register a listener for change events.
    */
   registerOnChange(fn: Function): void { this._onChange.push(fn); }
```

It allows to pass many listeners, but it really does not seem to be intended as a standard way *(for all controls)*, using standard observers *(no way how to dispose that listener)*

There is a link to the [`valueChanges` of the `AbsractControl`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts#L203)

```
export abstract class AbstractControl {
    ...
    /**
     * Emits an event every time the value of the control changes, in
     * the UI or programmatically.
     */
    get valueChanges(): Observable<any> { return this._valueChanges; }
```

And that means - **intended and ready for all `controls`**, following standard Observable pattern. That is a preferred way

Comment: thanks, what about `registerOnDisabledChange` method? Can it be replaced with something similar to `valueChanges`?

Comment: Yes.. check [statusChanges](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/src/model.ts#L208)... it passes the status value and if `DISABLED` is coming.. we can do your stuff

Comment: I switch back from `registerOnChange` to `valueChanges`, the former one did not always fired every changes as expected

Answer (score 7):

`registerOnChange` is mostly for internal use (AFAIR used by `CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR` and only allows a single subscriber) - therefore definitely use `valueChanges` instead.

Comment: thanks, what about `registerOnDisabledChange` method? Can it be replaced with something similar to `valueChanges`?